# Unknown column: I'm trying to get foreign keys but my application is closing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PLOT = "create table "
        + TABLE_PLOT + "(" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + GROWER_PLOT_AREA+ " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + GROWER_IRRIGATION_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + PLOT_SURVEY_NUM + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + VILLAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + WATER_DEPTH + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
        + GROWER_PLOT_ID + "INT ," + " FOREIGN KEY (" + GROWER_PLOT_ID + ") REFERENCES "
        + TABLE_MEMBER + " ("+ID_COLUMN +"));";
```

My application is crashing.
What's the problem with my code?

Comment: foreign key is not working in sqllite

Comment: is thr any solution for that..how to do

Comment: @VishalPatoliya It actually depends on your SQLite version. Foreign keys have been introduced in version **3.6.19**: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ GROWER_PLOT_ID + "INT ," + " FOREIGN KEY (" + GROWER_PLOT_ID + ") REFERENCES "
```

is causing your error, since `FOREIGN` is being included in the query field list.
Remove the extra comma after `INT`.
Also add a space before `INT`

```
+ GROWER_PLOT_ID + " INT FOREIGN KEY (" + GROWER_PLOT_ID + ") REFERENCES "
```

Comment: can any one help me how to insert the data into database by using the key_ value function